# How to make a custom FrameLayout with a cover?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-custom-view

Looking to make a small Android Compound View/Custom Component, where a FrameLayout is extended so that it has its own fully overlaying "Cover" view (that can intercept clicks and ripple) without repeating that cover in every XML instance.

I don't know whether it is best practice to re-layout the covering View in the Custom FrameLayout's onMeasure or onLayout methods, or if there's a simple XML trick that I'm missing (outside of just using a RelativeView since that would draw and re-draw the layout very often, but if I'm wrong here too correct me please)

CoveredFrameLayout.class

```
public class CoveredFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    private View coverView;

    public CoveredFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CoveredFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CoveredFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, @AttrRes int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        inflate(context, R.layout.widget_covered_framelayout, this);

        //

        setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.light_red));

        coverView = findViewById(R.id.widget_cover);

        //

        coverView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                coverView.animate()
                        .alpha(0)
                        .setDuration(1000)
                        .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                coverView.setVisibility(GONE);
                            }
                        })
                        .start();
                view.setOnClickListener(null);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    }
}
```

widget_covered_framelayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/widget_cover"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent_yellow400"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</merge>
```

The XML CoveredFrameLayout being used

```
    <com.example.oliver.content.ui.widgets.CoveredFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="hello" />

    </com.example.oliver.content.ui.widgets.CoveredFrameLayout>
```

And here's a screenshot of what this is looking like currently.  Just trying to learn the best practice to get that yellow square to dynamically cover the whole FrameLayout!  Thanks y'all!

[image]

Here is the end goal result, however this result was only achieved by hardcoding the Cover View's height and width to the pre-calculated height and width in pixels of the view itself.  A dynamic version of this could work fine, but I don't know what is the best practice for where in the onMeasure/onLayout cycle to put this code.

[image]

Comment: `"Just trying to learn the best practice to get that yellow square to dynamically cover the whole FrameLayout!"`, so replace `20dp` and `20dp` with `match_parent` and `match_parent`

Comment: A good idea, but unfortunately that then overrides the wrap_content height and width of the framelayout and its children, and takes up the whole height and width of the [screen](http://imgur.com/uoIpzYU)

Comment: @pskink edit, realized I didn't at you in the comment

Comment: it covers the whole `CoveredFrameLayout`, isnt it what you want?

Comment: @pskink, yes, but the point as to why this is arguably more interesting & slightly more complicated, is that I want the `CoveredFrameLayout` with width and height as `WRAP_CONTENT` and some children to still have the exactly the same size as a standard `FrameLayout` with width and height as `WRAP_CONTENT` and the same children.


The goal screenshot would have the transparent yellow cover covering the whole red rectangle (making it orange), but with the red rectangle still being only slightly larger (8dp padding) than the text "hello"

Comment: sorry man i have no idea what you mean, maybe some pic?

Comment: @pskink http://imgur.com/CthvSgU This is the goal image (will update the question), but this is only a result of manually setting the cover View to have hardcoded height and width as the pixel values of the widget itself.  I'd be fine to do this in a more dynamic way, but don't know if its better practice to manually set the Cover View's height and width in the CoverFrameLayout's overridden onMeasure or onLayout

Comment: ok execute `adb shell dumpsys activity top` and show me on the UI tree what elements do you want to cover with your orange overlay

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151530/discussion-between-ogoldbart3-and-pskink).